# Google Sheets - generate sublist / filtered group

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list that contains:

```
Column A-Name; Column B-Group
```

Group is a number from 1 to 10.

Next I have columns with group headings 1, 2, 3...10

What I want is under each Group# to list the names that belong to that group.

Any idea if this can be done in google sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell **C2** type:

```
=FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=C$1)
```

And then drag it across to **L2**